# How do fractional numbers of "prizes awarded" work?

Tags: support, diablo-3

25% of the number of people who reaching various acts will be the number of prizes awarded in each class up to some limit.  How will it work if a non-multiple of 4 number of people are in the bin?

- Rounded down? (conservative, but then if only 3 people reach Act IV, for example, nobody wins)
- Rounded up? (4 to 5 people would see everybody's odds go from 25% to 45% chance to win)
- Rounded down but minimum of one?

Comment: Could also be rounded traditionally (I.e. down at 5, up at 7, discretion of the team at 6)

Comment: We'll buy one of the prizes and cut it into pieces, of course

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz If it was rounded traditionally then it would also be up at 6.

Comment: Maybe everyone will win.  Or maybe [bees.](http://chzgifs.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/beesp1.gif)  Lord, I hope it's not the bees...

Comment: @agent86 "Beads" "Bees?" "*Beads*"

Answer (score 2):

Good question - since this wasn't clear in the rules, here's what we'll do:

If less than 4 people finish a level, we will still award one prize. If more than 4 people finish a level but it's not a multiple of 4, we'll use traditional rounding rules to determine the number of people to win prizes.

Comment: So [`max(1, int((X+2)/4))`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvR2Eb3lVDhIdGRER3FrWTdaR1J3LTRYbGVESjlqTGc#gid=4) then ([1,5]→1, [6,9]→2, [10,13]→3...)?

Answer (score 0):

Like this? (Unofficial unless someone of influence says otherwise)

[image]